# Echo json_encode not working on certain instances

Tags: php, json

I am currently using php to echo a json response to my webpage and am having trouble on certain instances. I can not figure out what is causing this though. I am using a sql statement that looks like this:

```
"SELECT * 
        FROM table
        WHERE id = $id
        LIMIT 20 OFFSET $offset"
```

The only thing that changes is the `$offset` when a user switches pages. I have 8 pages worth of data and pages 7 and 8 both do not return data while all the others do. When I copy this sql statement into my database for testing it retrieves data correctly.

Here how I am trying to echo the json:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];
    $row_array['description'] = $row['description'];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array); 
    //echo json_encode($return_arr);  <-- this returns JSON
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

On all the pages besides page 7 and 8 it returns the correct JSON but on these two pages for some reason the echo does nothing. If I put the json in the loop where I commented it out, it will return the correct json for pages 7 and 8 which is odd. I check that json in a validator and it is valid json. Any ways to check errors or debug this?

Comment: If I add the line to after the while it doesn't print anything. If I put it inside it does - same as with the echo - any idea there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is. What I think is probably happening is that some of your rows contain non-utf8 encoded characters. `json_encode` fails if this happens, returns nothing but false. You can check it by using an `is_bool`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
value
The value being encoded. Can be any type except a resource.

All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.
```

A naive solution to fix this is to do `mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');`, although the problem lies deeper and you should look into converting all your characters correctly to avoid missing bytes.

Comment: The line you suggested would go were relative to my php code? at the top?

Comment: For `mysqli_set_charset` you would put it before your query is run, so beat right after your `mysqli` declaration

Comment: if you can't retrieve the correct encoding a simple `htmlentities()` on the data should work

Comment: Yeah This worked. Someone had inserted the data in our table in Russian language thats why it wasn't json encoding

Comment: Since PHP7.2 you can do `json_encode($data,JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE)` to fix this craziness!